# kubernetes api-server understanding

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi i'm a newbie for k8s and i was wondering where and how kubectl sends requests to the kube api-server.
So for example, if i'm sending a request such as "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces"(and my default kubernetes endpoints is set as "192.168.64.2:8443"), my understanding is that this would translate to a https request such as "https://192.168.64.2:8443/api/v1/pods......etc" and kubectl would use authentication stored in .kube/config file. Am i right?

And i also have a metrics-server up and running on endpoint "172.17.0.8:4443" but how does kubectl know to use this ip when i run "kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/<NODE_NAME> | jq"? are all kubectl commands directed to one ip?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Kubernetes API Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) in the documentation might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is one of the steps that kubectl achieves. You could see what happens when a command run with verbose ability. for example,

```
kubectl get pods -v9 --all-namespaces
```

Kubernetes know resource definitions and their implementation, you could check resource types with,

```
 kubectl api-resources
```

So Kubernetes api-server knows which resources are metric-server and how that could call.

Answer (score 0):

All kubectl requests go to the api-server. The api-server can either answer by itself or it delegates to other components, for example an extension api server.